# How to get sites that are associated to Hub Site using Rest Api

Tags: sharepoint, rest

I have a hub site called TestingHub and TestingHubAssociated is associated to TestingHub .
How I have associated :

1. TestingHubAssociated - Site information - Associate to Hub site(TestingHub )
   through rest api  i am not able to get sites that are associated to HUB.
   URL : website/sites/TestingHub/_api/web/HubSiteData

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

There is no Direct API to Achieve this, however you can use Search API as workaround.

In the Query section, you just pass these.

> DepartmentId:3c6cddfa-378c-4fe1-b116-a59ce3d43d08 AND
> contentclass:STS_Site

just replace your Hub site ID with Department ID.

you can use Search Query Tools to Preview this.
https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Tools/releases

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no REST API to get the associated sites in a hub in the [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/features/hub-site/hub-site-rest-api).

HubSiteData command is aim to get hub site data for the current web,not to display all the sites associated with the hub site.

As a workaround, we could use following pnp powershell to get all sites associated with a Hub Site(this will contains the hub site itself):

```
#Variables
$AdminCenterURL = "https://tenant-admin.sharepoint.com"
$HubSiteURL = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/"
 
#Connect to Pnp Online
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminCenterURL  -Credentials (Get-Credential) #-UseWebLogin
 
#Get the hub site id
$HubSiteID = (Get-PnPTenantSite $HubSiteURL).HubSiteId
 
#Get all site collections associated with the hub site
Get-PnPTenantSite -Detailed | select url | ForEach-Object {
  $Site = Get-PnPTenantSite $_.url
  If($Site.HubSiteId -eq $HubSiteId){
    write-host $Site.url
  }
}
```

More inforamtion:

https://www.sharepointdiary.com/2019/12/get-all-sites-associated-with-sharepoint-online-hub-site-using-powershell.html